# Animate Shape Color in Android

Tags: android, animation, colors, shapes

I would like to create a loop somewhere in my Android code that changes the color of a drawable rectangle between two colors continuously at some rate. I would like to start and stop its blinking using two buttons. I have done a lot of research, but just can't seem to figure out how to do it. I am new to android and do not have experience with run() methods. But I am guessing I have to make some kind of rectangle class with a run() method that will animate it into changing colors.

Answer (score 2):

I am also fairly new to android, but I will give it a shot.

Since you say you want it to blink, you should be able to switch the actual image between, lets say, blue and red, with a simple 'for' loop. When the button is pressed, you could change the status of a boolean from false to true. Then, when the 'for' statement is not true anymore, it jumps to the next set of code, which stops it. Here is what I would do.

Your XML for the two buttons:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/start"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Start"
    android:Clickable="true"
    android:onClick="start"
     />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/stop" <!-- Gives the button an ID to use in java code -->
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Stop" <!-- sets the text on the button -->
    android:Clickable="true" <!-- makes the button clickable -->
    android:onClick="stop" <!-- The method it calls when it is clicked, removes the necessity of an OnClickListener -->
     />
```

Now, you would have 2 ImageViews: `blue_rectangle` and `red_rectangle`, both in the same place in the layout. Here is the XML for the two ImageViews

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/blue_rectangle"
android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="75dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:src="@drawable/blue_rectangle" />

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/red_rectangle"
android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="75dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:src="@drawable/red_rectangle" />
```

This next part is the tricky part.

Here is the Java.

```
package your.package.name.thingy.here;

//everything it tells you to import goes here

public class BlinkingActivity extends Activity{

 ImageView blueRectangle;
 ImageView redRectangle;
 Button start;
 Button stop;

    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.yourLayout);

    blueRectangle = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.blue_rectangle);
    redRectangle = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.red_rectangle);
    start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
    stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);
    Boolean isBlinking = new Boolean(false);

    blinkRectangle(whateverVariableThisNeeds);

}

public static void blinkRectangle(View view){

blueRectangle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
redRectangle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

for(initialization; isBlinking; update){

   blueRectangle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

   blueRectangle.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
   blueRectangle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
   }
   }, 2000); //the 2000 is the number of milliseconds for how long blue is visible
   redRectangle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

   redRectangle.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run(){
   redRectangle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
   }
   }, 2000);

   blueRectangle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //This prevents a bug where if the user hits the stop button at just the right time, both rectangles will be invisible.
}


public static void start(View view){ //no need to call this anywhere, the XML onClick does it for you

isBlinking = true; //I think this is how you set a boolean, if not, correct me.

}

public static void stop(View view){//same here

isBlinking = false; //again, correct me if I'm wrong.

}

}
```

Here is what the code basically does.

It has a boolean which is defaulted to false. While it is false, the rectangle does not blink. While it is true, the `for` statement in `blinkRectangle()` runs. That `for` loop makes the blue on visible, waits 2 seconds, makes it invisible, makes the red one visible, waits two seconds, and repeats. The `start()` and `stop()` methods switch the boolean to true and false, respectively. I think this type of `for` loop re-checks the boolean when it gets back to the top. I have never worked with it before. That's what I could gather from the website I looked at.

Well, I think that about does it. If you don't understand what any of the code does, or it doesn't work, or I have the question wrong, or I am just downright wrong, or ANYTHING, just comment on this answer. I hope this works!

Good Luck!

P.S. Here are the websites I used for reference

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_loop_control.htm

http://www.java-examples.com/java-boolean-example

Wow...I just realized this question is 2 years old. Still, I hope this helps you!

Comment: Don't worry, you [get badges for that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10874571/how-does-check-ajax-referer-really-work/18358174#comment27016156_18358174) ([Necromancer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/17/necromancer)) and upvotes will prove its usefulness ;)