# How to call ajax function that will call my plugin's function

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have the following function in my plugin

```
function IsIdInProject($id=null){
    if ($id=="test")
    {
      return true;
    }
     return false;
    }
```

I need to call this function from my page using jquery, but I do not understand what to put in my url parameter.

This code is located in settings.php page of my plugin (plugins/myplugin/settings.php)

I cannot just call `url: mywebsite.com/plugins/myplugins/settings.php`, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using AJAX in a WordPress plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17855846/using-ajax-in-a-wordpress-plugin)

Answer (score -1):

try to use action `wp_ajax`

[Demo](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/using-ajax-with-wordpress/)

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );
function my_action_callback() {
$var ="no var";
$id=$_REQUEST['id'];
 if ($id=="test")
{
 $var=$id;
}
echo $var;

    wp_die(); // this is required 
}
```

Comment: Okay. thanks Where do I put this code? And how do I call this function from JS?

Comment: please check demo links

Comment: if my answer is right please upvote and tick beside my answer to make my answer as solution thx.

Comment: Please describe the process some more. Linking to demos and copy-pasting generic code is not that helpful.

Comment: please check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17855846/using-ajax-in-a-wordpress-plugin