# Wordpress, Javascript and Php : Am I placing authenticate-user.php in the right folder?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, exists

I am new to PHP and WordPress development.
On my WordPress page I want to check whether the `aff_id` in my page's query string is present as a user in my WordPress DB using AJAX.

Below is the JavaScript which I have placed on my WP page using "Scripts and styles" plugin:

```
var affId = '';
affId = GetParameterValues('aff_id'); 
if (affId == undefined || affId == '')
  affId = 'AKotawala';
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = function () {
  alert(this.responseText);
};
xhr.open("POST", "../wp-includes/authenticate-user.php");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.send("username=" + affId);
function GetParameterValues(param) {  
  var url = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');  
  for (var i = 0; i < url.length; i++) {  
    var urlparam = url[i].split('=');  
    if (urlparam[0] == param) {  
      return urlparam[1];  
    }  
  }  
}
```

And here's my PHP code

**authenticate-user.php**

```
<?php  
$username = $_POST['username'];
if (my_username_exists($username))
  echo "Exist";
else
  echo "NotExist";
function my_username_exists($username) {
  global $wpdb;
  $count = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT COUNT(user_login) FROM $wpdb->users WHERE user_login = %s", $username));
  return empty( $count ) || 1 > $count ? false : true;
}
?>
```

When the page loads my alert box is empty.

What am I doing wrong?

When I hard code the `$username` variable in my PHP and run the file as `mydomain.com/wp-includes/authenticate-user.php` it returns a blank page.

Am I placing `authenticate-user.php` in the right folder?
If yes what should be the url I should pass to my AJAX function in JS?

Comment: Don't use ajax in WordPress this way, Try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18614405/5638658) instead

Answer (score 0):

try including this in your `authenticate-user.php` file and place the file in the root directory.

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-config.php');
```

or give the relative path from the current directory

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '../wp-config.php');
```

Comment: checked and updated the code... check this on your code