# Ajax call in WP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I am creating a button to send an email to the logged-in user's branch.
Just to begin coding this, I need to send an AJAX call successfully, triggering the 'success' method of the AJAX object.

I have read that the proper way is as below, using a wp_localize() function to make the admin-ajax.php file URL available in my Javascript.But it is not working.

I have tested that the enquiry() function is getting called successfully, so the script is properly enqueued.

This is my PHP plugin code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button','ajax_register_script');
function ajax_register_script()
{
    wp_register_script('mailer-script', plugins_url('/ajax-script.js', __FILE__),
        array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('mailer-script', plugins_url('/ajax-script.js', __FILE__),
        array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
    wp_localize_script( 'mailer-script', 'mailer_ajax', 
        array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')) );
}


add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'button_function', 45);

function button_function()
{
    echo "<div class='unique' id='mail-button' onclick='enquiry()'>
  Not sure of your prescription? Click to be contacted</div>";
}
```

and this is my JS:

```
function enquiry() {

  $.ajax({
         url: mailer_ajax.ajax_url,
         type: 'post',
         data: {
            action: 'go',
           },
        success: function () {
             document.getElementById('mail-button').innerHTML =  "Thankyou for your enquiry, an email has been sent to your branch. You will be contacted shortly";
        },

    })
};
```

Thanks very much for any insight.

Comment: what exactly you want to do? what problem are you facing here and what have you tried so far??

Comment: I would like to make the 'success ' method fire as a result of a successful AJAX call. Sorry if that was not clear. Will edit

Comment: After lots of neatening up and refactoring my code is working.  
I wish i knew exactly what the problem was, as in principle the above seems to be correct.
A great help was rams0610's answer on this question.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17855846/using-ajax-in-a-wordpress-plugin/18614405#18614405

Answer (score 0):

After lots of neatening up and refactoring my code is working.
I wish i knew exactly what the problem was, as in principle the above seems to be correct.
A great help was rams0610's answer on this question.

[Using AJAX in a WordPress plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17855846/using-ajax-in-a-wordpress-plugin/18614405#18614405)