# Ajax return issue in a WordPress plugin

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am creating a WordPress plugin and I have a strange issue.

First of all I like to show my WordPress script.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Banner Plugin
*/

define( 'MYPLUGINNAME_PATH', plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) );
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'my_banner_plugin_activate' );
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'my_banner_plugin_deactivate' );

function my_banner_plugin_activate(){
    //Activation method.
    activate();
}

function my_banner_plugin_deactivate(){
    //Deactivation method.
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->query(" DROP TABLE ".$wpdb->prefix."banner ");
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'register_custom_menu_page');

function register_custom_menu_page() {
  add_menu_page( 'Banner Menu Display', 'Banner Menu', 'read', 'banner-menu', 'display_banner_panel' /*, $icon_url, $position*/ );
  add_submenu_page( 'banner-menu', 'Add Baner', 'Add Baner','read', 'add-banner','display_banner_subpanel_add');
} 

if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action']=='add_banner'){
    submit_form();
}

if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action']=='updateRecordsListings')
{
    include 'reorder.php';
}

function header_css_page() {
    wp_register_style($handle = 'header-css', $src = plugins_url('css/banner_style.css', __FILE__), $deps = array(), $ver = '1.0.0', $media = 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('header-css');
}

add_action('init', 'header_css_page');

function reorder_css_page() {
    wp_register_style($handle = 'reorder-css', $src = plugins_url('css/reorder_style.css', __FILE__), $deps = array(), $ver = '1.0.0', $media = 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('reorder-css');
}

add_action('init', 'reorder_css_page');

function display_banner_panel()
{  
    global $wpdb;
    $banner_list = $wpdb->get_results("select * from ".$wpdb->prefix."banner order by banner_order desc");
    ?>
    <div class='admin-custom'>
    <?php  include 'view_banner.php'; ?>  
     </div>
<?php
}
```

The script for `view_banner.php` is as follows;

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo plugins_url();?>/banner-pluggin/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo plugins_url();?>/banner-pluggin/js/jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(function() {
        $("#contentLeft2 ul").sortable({ opacity: 0.6, cursor: 'move', update: function() {
            var order = $(this).sortable("serialize") + '&action=updateRecordsListings'; 
            $.post("", order, function(theResponse){
                $("#contentRight2").html(theResponse);
            });                                                              
        }                                 
        });
    });
}); 
</script>
</head>
    <body>
    <h1>Add Banner</h1>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="contentWrap2">
        <div id="contentLeft2">
            <ul>
                <?php
                //$query  = "SELECT * FROM records ORDER BY recordListingID ASC";
                //$result = mysql_query($query);

                //while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
                //{
                                foreach($banner_list as $row)
                                {
                ?>
                            <li id="recordsArray_<?php echo $row->banner_id; ?>">
                                <div>
                                    <img src="<?php echo plugins_url().'/banner-pluggin/banner/'. $row->banner_img;?>" height="80px" width="100px"/>
                                </div>
                            </li>

                                            <?php } ?>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="contentRight2">
          <p>Array will be displayed here.</p>
          <p>&nbsp; </p>
        </div>

    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the `reorder.php` is as follows;

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
    $action    = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['action']);
    $updateRecordsArray     = $_POST['recordsArray'];

    if ($action == "updateRecordsListings")
    {
        $listingCounter = 1;
        foreach ($updateRecordsArray as $recordIDValue) 
            {

            $query = "UPDATE wp_banner SET banner_order = " . $listingCounter . " WHERE banner_id = " . $recordIDValue;
            if(mysql_query($query))
            {

            }
            else {
                mysql_error(); 
            }//die('Error, insert query failed');
            $listingCounter = $listingCounter + 1;
            }

        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($updateRecordsArray);
        echo '</pre>';
        echo 'If you refresh the page, you will see that records will stay just as you modified.';
    }
?>
```

The problem is that the ajax calling is also working fine, the only problem is that the ajax response also displays the part of the admin menus,

here's a screenshot:
[image]

On the green box at the right, the portion of the admin shouldn't be shown, but why is it showing up?

I know I figured out the problem,

```
$.post("", order, function(theResponse)
```

Causes the Ajax call to be sent to the same page that means `banner-pluggin.php`
and after the action the html of the `banner-pluggin.php` is getting loaded as in Ajax.

But if I directly send the Ajax post to `reorder.php`, then since there is no HTML, the HTML won't be loaded as response.

But then another issue: the SQL query doesn't run, neither it shows any error, nor SQL gets executed

Answer (score 0):

Too many issues with your code, I suggest starting from scratch.

ISSUES:

1. You should not embed a full HTML page in your submenu page (`view-banner.php`).
2. CSS and Javascript should be added with `admin_enqueue_scripts` and only in ***your plugin's page***, not *everywhere* like it's happening now with the `init` action hook.
3. I don't understand how you managed to make Ajax work, but it is surely not the proper way.

STARTING AGAIN:

1. Research the [`<plugin-development>`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin-development?sort=votes) tag at WordPress Answers, you'll find many nice examples of how to add your plugin page and render its contents. I always use this [Plugin Class Demo](https://gist.github.com/toscho/3804204) from [one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/73/toscho) of our moderators as starting point for a new plugin.
2. Some working examples of Ajax in WordPress: [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13498959/1287812), [[2]](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/106427/12615) and [[3]](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/54875/12615).