# Retrieving Data from DAtabase using Ajax in WordPress Plugin

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I am trying to retrieve a tuple from database table using ajax method in my WordPress plugin

Here's my album-plugin script

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Album Pluggin

*/
define( 'MYPLUGINNAME_PATH', plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) );
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'my_album_pluggin_activate' );
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'my_album_pluggin_deactivate' );


function my_album_pluggin_activate(){
    //Activation method.
    activate_album_pluggin();
}

function my_album_pluggin_deactivate(){
    //Deactivation method.
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->query(" DROP TABLE ".$wpdb->prefix."album ");
        $wpdb->query(" DROP TABLE ".$wpdb->prefix."image ");
}


add_action( 'admin_footer', 'my_action_javascript' );

function my_action_javascript() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript" >

function get_album_data(album_id)
{
    alert('album_id is '+album_id);
    var data = {
        action: 'my_action',
        album_id: album_id
    };
        $.post(ajaxurl,data,
                        function(res)
                            {
                                var message_result = eval('(' + res + ')');
                                alert(message_result.album_name);
                            }
                        );
}
</script>
<?php
}

add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback');

function my_action_callback() {
    global $wpdb;
    $album_id=$_POST['album_id'];
    $res = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."album WHERE album_id='$album_id'");
    echo json_encode($res);
    die();

}


add_action('admin_menu', 'register_custom_album_menu_page');

function register_custom_album_menu_page() {
  add_menu_page( 'Album Menu Display', 'Album Menu', 'read', 'album-menu', 'display_album_panel' /*, $icon_url, $position*/ );
  add_submenu_page( 'album-menu', 'Add Album', 'Add Album','read', 'add-album','display_album_subpanel_add');
  add_submenu_page( 'album-menu', 'Edit Album', 'Edit Album','read', 'edit-album','display_album_subpanel_edit');
} 





if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action']=='add_album'){
    submit_album_form();
}


if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action']=='updateRecordsListings')
{
    include 'reorder.php';
}







function header_album_css_page() {

    wp_register_style($handle = 'header-css', $src = plugins_url('css/album_style.css', __FILE__), $deps = array(), $ver = '1.0.0', $media = 'all');

    wp_enqueue_style('header-css');
}

add_action('init', 'header_album_css_page');

function reorder_album_css_page() {

    wp_register_style($handle = 'reorder-css', $src = plugins_url('css/reorder_style.css', __FILE__), $deps = array(), $ver = '1.0.0', $media = 'all');

    wp_enqueue_style('reorder-css');
}

add_action('init', 'reorder_album_css_page');


function display_album_panel()
{  
    global $wpdb;
    $banner_list = $wpdb->get_results("select * from ".$wpdb->prefix."album order by album_order desc");
    ?>
    <div class='admin-custom'>
    <?php  include 'view_album.php'; ?>  

     </div>


<?php
}
function display_album_subpanel_add()
{   ?>
    <div class='admin-custom'>
    <?php  include 'add_album.php'; ?>  

     </div>
    <?php 

}
function display_album_subpanel_edit()
{   
    global $wpdb;
    $res = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."album ORDER BY album_order ASC");
    ?>
    <div class='admin-custom'>
    <?php  include 'edit_album.php'; ?>  

     </div>
    <?php 

}
/*add_shortcode('DISPLAY-BANNER-SLIDER','func_display_banner');

function func_display_banner(){
        global $wpdb;

        $res = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."banner ORDER BY banner_order DESC");
        $path = ABSPATH . 'wp-content/plugins/banner-pluggin/banner/';



        $html = '<!-- banner slider-->
                                    <div id="header">
                                       <div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
                                       <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">';
        foreach($res as $row){ 

        $html .='<img src="'.plugins_url().'/banner-pluggin/banner/'. $row->banner_img  .'" alt="" title="'.$row->banner_content.'">';

        }

        $html .= '</div>
                        </div>
                        </div>        
                                    <!--//slider-->';
    return $html;   
}*/

function activate_album_pluggin(){
    global $wpdb;
        /*if(!file_exists(ABSPATH .'wp-content/plugins/banner-pluggin/banner/'))
                        mkdir(ABSPATH .'wp-content/plugins/banner-pluggin/banner/');*/

    $sql_album  = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ".$wpdb->prefix."album (
            album_id INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
            album_name VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
                        album_slug VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
            album_content TEXT NOT NULL ,
            album_order INT( 11 ) NOT NULL,
                        album_timestamp VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL

        )";
    $sql_image = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ".$wpdb->prefix."image (
            image_id INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
            image_name VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
                        image_slug VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
            image_img VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
            image_content TEXT NOT NULL ,
            album_id INT( 11 ) NOT NULL,
                        image_order INT( 11 ) NOT NULL,
                        image_status INT( 11 ) NOT NULL,
                        image_timestamp VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL
        )"; 
    $wpdb->query($sql_album);
        $wpdb->query($sql_image);
}

function submit_album_form(){
    global $wpdb;



    $albumname = $_POST['album_name'];
        $albumcontent = $_POST['album_content'];
        $albumtimestamp = time();
    $imagename = $_POST['image_name'];

    $wpdb->insert( 
        $wpdb->prefix."album", 
        array( 
            'album_name' => $albumname, 
            'album_content' => $albumcontent,
                        'album_timestamp' => $albumtimestamp

                    ), 
        array( 
            '%s', 
                        '%s', 
            '%s'
        ) 
    );
        $album_info = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."album WHERE album_timestamp='".$albumtimestamp."'");
    foreach($album_info as $row)
        {
            $id=$row->album_id;
        }
        $albumslug=$id."-".make_slug($albumname);
        $update_data=array(
                            'album_slug'=>$albumslug
                          );
        if(!file_exists(ABSPATH .'wp-content/plugins/album-pluggin/'.$albumslug.'/'))
                        mkdir(ABSPATH .'wp-content/plugins/album-pluggin/'.$albumslug.'/');
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["album_img"]["tmp_name"],ABSPATH . 'wp-content/plugins/album-pluggin/'.$albumslug.'/' . $_FILES["album_img"]["name"]))
                echo "done";
        else
                echo "error";
        $wpdb->update(
                        $wpdb->prefix."album", // Table
                        $update_data, // Array of key(col) => val(value to update to)
                        array(
                            'album_timestamp' => $albumtimestamp
                             ) // Where
                     );




        $image_link='wp-content/plugins/album-pluggin/'.$albumslug.'/'. $_FILES["album_img"]["name"];
        $image_timestamp=intval(time()+10);
        $wpdb->insert( 
        $wpdb->prefix."image", 
        array( 
            'image_name' => $imagename, 
            'album_id' => $id,
                        'image_img'=>$image_link,
                        'image_timestamp' => $image_timestamp

                    ), 
        array( 
            '%s', 
                        '%d',
                        '%s', 
            '%s'
        ) 
    );
        $image_info = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."image WHERE image_timestamp='".$image_timestamp."'");
    foreach($image_info as $irow)
        {
            $i_id=$irow->image_id;
        }
        $imageslug=$id."-".make_slug($imagename);
        $update_image_data=array(
                            'image_slug'=>$imageslug
                          );
        $wpdb->update(
                        $wpdb->prefix."image", // Table
                        $update_image_data, // Array of key(col) => val(value to update to)
                        array(
                            'image_timestamp' => $image_timestamp
                             ) // Where
                     );


}

function make_slug($data)
     {
         $data_slug = trim($data," ");
         $search = array('/','\\',':',';','!','@','#','$','%','^','*','(',')','_','+','=','|','{','}','[',']','"',"'",'<','>',',','?','~','`','&',' ','.');
         $data_slug = str_replace($search, "_", $data_slug);
         return $data_slug;
     }

    /* add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'prefix_add_my_stylesheet' );

    function prefix_add_my_stylesheet() {
        wp_register_style( 'custom-style', plugins_url('style.css', __FILE__) );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-style' );
    }*/

    ?>
```

and here's my edit_album script

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo plugins_url();?>/album-pluggin/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

</head>
    <body>
    <h1>Add Album</h1>
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <input name="action" type="hidden" value="edit_album"/>
        <div class="label_div">
            <span class="label_data">Select Album</span>
        </div>
        <div class="text_div">
            <select class="text_data" name="album_id" onchange="get_album_data(this.value);">
                <option value="0">Select Album</option>
                <?php
                foreach($res as $r)
                {?>
                <option value="<?php echo $r->album_id;?>"><?php echo $r->album_name;?></option>
                <?php
                }?>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="clear_div"></div>
        <div class="label_div">
            <span class="label_data">Album Name</span>
        </div>
        <div class="text_div">
            <input class="text_data" name="album_name" id="album_name" type="text"/>
        </div>
        <div class="clear_div"></div>
        <div class="label_div">
            <span class="label_data">Album Image</span>
        </div>
        <div class="text_div">
            <input name="album_img" type="file"/>
        </div>
        <div class="clear_div"></div>
        <div class="label_div">
            <span class="label_data">Image Name</span>
        </div>
        <div class="text_div">
            <input name="image_name" type="text"/>
        </div>
        <div class="clear_div"></div>
        <div class="label_div">
           <span class="label_data">Album content</span>
        </div>
        <div class="text_div">
            <textarea class="textarea_data" name="album_content" cols="" rows=""></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="clear_div"></div>

        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Add Banner">
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

the issue is that the script portion

```
function(res)
                            {
                                var message_result = eval('(' + res + ')');
                                alert(message_result.album_name);
                            }
```

is always alerting undefined.

I think I have made some issues regarding json encoding, or maybe I am not parsing it properly.

Comment: When and where are you calling your function get_album_data?

Comment: look into the edit_album.php file, its being called by the onchange event of the select

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, as i was trying for different approaches, i founa a solution out of the situtaion

i changed the script my_action_javascript() with the following changes

```
function my_action_javascript() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript" >

function get_album_data(album_id)
{
    alert('album_id is '+album_id);
    var data = {
        action: 'my_action',
        album_id: album_id
    };
        $.post(ajaxurl,data,
                    function(res)
                        {
                            alert(res);
                            alert(res[0].album_name);
                        },'json'
                    );
}
</script>
<?php
}
```

and bingo i got the result,

since $res is a resultant array with a single tuple. hence the 0th row will be the carrier of my desired result..

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13614297/1287812) and [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/110937/12615).