# Display posts by date using AJAX?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Need a little push in the right direction.
I have a fairly standard `<ul>` which outputs this:

```
2013
September
2012
September
```

I am using wordpress so I yanked them from my $wpdb accordingly and into a nice little sidebar. Right now the main content area is filled with the latest posts from a single category, using the standard `if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post();` method.

My aim is to be able to click on the month, under a year, loading the posts from that year and month into the main content area. I assume the best way to do this is AJAX, but I'm not sure how to go about it. I've done some very simple ajax stuff before, but I'm just lacking the experience to know how to go about doing this.

My assumption is I do something like:

```
click.doSmething, get date/year, $args=date/year, html = if(have_posts()..., echo html;
```

Obviously on the server side.

Any help on filling in the gaps?

Comment: Too many gaps to fill, start with a [working example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13614297/1287812).

Comment: I thought as much :/ thanks, I'll take a look at your link.