# Wordpress voting system with ajax call and php function not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to create a voting system for my Wordpress blog, but the code I've written does not update the metadata field created for the votes and each time i call the function to add a vote I get the value 1 returned,

***Here is the code I've written:***

First in the html part of the post I've created a link which calls the **loadurl()** via javascript:

```
<a  onclick="loadurl()" class='voteup' title="به این پست یه امتیاز"><i class="icon-angle-up"></i></a>
```

the script for the **loadurl()** call is as below which uses ajax to call the **call_me()** function from the **functions.php** file

```
function loadurl() {
var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';
    var value = $.ajax({

      type: "POST",
      url: ajaxurl,
      data:{
            //the call_me function for adding a vote in the functions.php
        action: 'call_me'
        }
    })
     .fail(function(r,status,jqXHR) {
         console.log('failed');
     })
     .done(function(r,status,jqXHR) {

          console.log('success');
          //r is the return value of the function call_me();
          console.log(r);
    });
}
```

and finally in the **functions.php** file I've added an action hook (which i'm not really certain about) and the function body who is supposed to get the currentvotes and after adding 1 to the current vote update it as the new vote count:

```
<?php  
   add_action('wp_ajax_noPriv_call_me', 'call_me');
   add_action('wp_ajax_call_me', 'call_me');
   add_action('save_post', 'call_me');

   function call_me() { 
      global $wpdb;
      $currentvotes = get_post_meta($_POST['post'], 'votes', true);
      $currentvotes = $currentvotes + 1;
      update_post_meta($_POST['post'], 'votes', $currentvotes);
      echo $currentvotes;   
      die();
   }
?>
```

but the currentvotes value outputed from the console.log(r) function in the loadurl() functions is always 1,

Comment: You are calling the function call_me during the save_post, as opposed to AJAX call on front facing side. Anyway.. can you check if( !empty( $_POST['post'] ) ) in that function ? Also try to pass the post id as data in the AJAX call along with the action. Also 'ajax_noPriv_' should be in lower case.

Comment: how do I pass the post id data to the callme() function?

Comment: data:{
        action: 'call_me',
  post: '22'
      }   
http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins#Separate_Javascript_File

Comment: I think @Subharanjan nailed it, how do you know `$_POST['post']` contains a valid post ID? Important: don't use `'post'`, that's a reserved name, prefix all your custom vars. Also, you're missing security checks too, see [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13614297/1287812).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that I wasn't passing the PostID to the **callme()** function and for some reason wasn't able to get the postID once I was inside the php function in functions.php.
So I added the *id* variable which stored the postID in it:

```
var id= <?php the_ID();?>;
```

and then passed it to the callme() function by adding the following to the ajax call:

```
'id': id,
```

so now the ajax call looks something like this:

```
function loadurl() {

var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';
var id= <?php the_ID();?>;
var value = $.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    url: ajaxurl,
    data:{
        'id': id,
        action: 'call_me'

        }

    })
     .fail(function(r,status,jqXHR) {
         console.log('failed');

     })
     .done(function(r,status,jqXHR) {
        /*console.log('success');*/
        console.log(r);

     });

}
```

now with `$id= $_REQUEST['id'];` I can retrieve the postID from which the Ajax call was made and with the following function I can read the vote value from the corresponding metadata stored for the post and return it to the ajax call:

```
<?php  
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_call_me', 'call_me');
add_action('wp_ajax_call_me', 'call_me');


function call_me(){ 
 $id= $_REQUEST['id'];

    $currentvotes = get_post_meta($id, 'votes', true);
    $currentvotes = $currentvotes + 1;
    update_post_meta($id, 'votes', $currentvotes);

echo $currentvotes ;
die();
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi, Farzan, I tried your solution, but I get `Cannot read property 'ajax' of undefined` error. Do you think your answer might need update since 2013? Thanks!