# Correct location for Ajax Scripts in Wordpress?

Tags: ajax, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to Ajax up an admin screen (admin.php) in a Wordpress plugin I'm experimenting with which currently just reads the contents of a table, and should allows a row to be entered into the table.  At the moment I'm getting the following error when submitting the new row.  It doesn't seem to matter where I put the ajax script in the files.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: addtablerow is not defined
```

So, within my class-plugin.php, I create a new page under the Settings menu (views/admin.php), and I have a function which pulls out the contents of a table and displays it.  I then create a new blank row row of input fields the bottom of the table, and add a div to put the ajax feedback:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="new_wp_pop_date_modifiers">   
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="pop_addtablerow_php"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="table" value="wp_pop_date_modifiers"/> 
  <tr class="manage-column">
    <td><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="description" placeholder="description"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="sort_order" placeholder="sort_order"></td>
    <td><input type="Submit"></td>
  </tr>
</form>

<div id="feedback_wp_pop_date_modifiers">Feedback:</div> 
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery('#new_wp_pop_date_modifiers').submit(addtablerow);
</script>
```

The php handler is the file class-plugin.php, function pop_addtablerow_php:

```
function pop_addtablerow_php(){
  global $wpdb;

  $data =array();
  foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
    if (($key != 'table') && ($key !='action')) {
        $data[$key] .= $value;
    }
  }

  if($wpdb->insert($_POST['table'],$data)===FALSE){
      echo "Error";
    } else {
      echo "Value '".$name. "' successfully added to '".$table."', row ID is ".$wpdb->insert_id;
  }
  die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_pop_addtablerow_php', 'pop_addtablerow_php');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_pop_addtablerow_php', 'pop_addtablerow_php');
```

And then I have my ajax stuff, which, no  matter where I put it, gives me the above error:

```
<script type="javascript/text">
function addtablerow(){
    var rowdata = jQuery(this).serialize();
    jQuery.ajax({
        type:"POST",    
        url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        data: rowdata,
        success:function(data){
            jQuery("#feedback_wp_pop_date_modifiers_").html(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Even if I just place this inline in admin.php - thhe admin screen I am creating for the plugin - is still gives me the Uncaught ReferenceError.  I'm not sure if I've just got something in the wrong place, or if there is a bigger error somewhere

This is my first stab at using Ajax, so any pointers as to where I'm going wrong would be much appreciated

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13614297/1287812).

Answer (score 0):

Probably has something to do with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery('#new_wp_pop_date_modifiers').submit(addtablerow);
</script>
```

What is addtablerow in the submit argument?

Comment: addtablerow is the javascript function

Comment: The Uncaught Reference error is javascript. you can either replace the pointer to the function with the function itself, or you can add the argument of e to the function's method signature