# WordPress have_posts() not working inside Functions.php

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, function, wordpress-theming

I want to ajaxify TwentyThirteen WordPress template and I have a function in functions.php

```
function prefix_ajax_add_foobar() {
    echo("add_foobar is trigered <br/>");
    if ( have_posts() ) { echo ("have posts <br/>");
        while ( have_posts() ) {
            the_post(); echo ("the_post() <br/>");
            the_ID(); echo ("the_ID() <br/>");
        } 
    }
    die("The End");
}
```

But I only see those results:

```
add_foobar is trigered 
The End
```

So can you give me an idea why those functions are not working?

Comment: Well, the only thing that would stop them working would be if `have_posts()` returns false. How is this function being called? Is there a `$wpdb` query that's active at that point?

Comment: I don't know, I haven't done anything, I thought wp would automatically activate it. Because this piece of code is paced in index.php file, after including the header.php, it doesn't activates db. So what you suggest? What should I do?

Comment: Where did you get the code from? Were there instructions with it?

Comment: Tell us, where do you call your function `prefix_ajax_add_foobar`, or how do you use it.

Comment: Anything else is working RIGHT, like a charm, only this function has problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you have to make your own query in that function, Ajax isn't aware of your current loop. And you'd be better using `get_posts()`, see [When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1753)

It'll be something like:

```
$my_query = get_posts( $arguments );
if( $my_query ) {
    foreach( $my_query as $p ) {
        echo $p->ID . $p->post_title;
    }
}
```

Comment: I just updated a full WP Ajax example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13614297), check the history of the post as the first version was with a theme. And now it's a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

`have_posts()` will return TRUE if it has any results to loop over and FALSE otherwise. It does seem that it is currently not getting any results. Have you tried calling `query_posts($args)`? Call it before the `have_posts()`
Example:
`query_posts( 'posts_per_page=5' );` to show your 5 latest posts