# get_the_id() not returning ID's of posts

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to dynamically load blocks via AJAX:

- Blocks with the ID's 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 are loaded by default on the page.
- On "Load more" click, five new blocks will show (with the ID's 6,7, 8, 9 and 10).

However, I currently can't even get the ID's of the new blocks to echo out on the page and I'm unsure why? I've tried globalising the var too.

Current approach (**ajax-loaders.php**):

```
function ajax_handler(){

  check_ajax_referer('load_more', 'security');

  $args = json_decode(( $_POST['query'] ), true ); 

  global $postId;
  $postId = get_the_id($args);

  if( $args->have_posts() ) : 
    while( have_posts() ): the_post(); 
      echo "the ID of this post is:".$postId;
    endwhile;
  endif;
  die;
}
```

In console, I get an post error.

And if I do:

echo "the ID of this post is:".$postId;
   var_dump($args);

It returns *the ID of this post is:NULL*.

Unsure on what's happening?

Comment: What exactly is being $_POSTed? Also, your loop makes no sense inside an ajax call... Did you check the documentation for [`get_the_id()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_id/)?? What you need is `get_posts` and it has a different loop. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/19598561/1287812

Answer (score 1):

Simple [get_the_id()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_id/) works within the WP loop and you've put it outside the loop. try:

```
echo "the ID of this post is:" . get_the_id();
```

Outside the loop:

```
global $post;
postId = $post->ID;
```

Comment: Actually I don't know what is $args in your case, but get_the_id method works within the WP loop