# Bulk Update Post Meta with AJAX and onclick

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I want to update posts meta value in the wp_query to a different value on click. What I am basically doing is making a notification bubble (like stackoverflow).

1. wp_query with the number of posts that have meta value 'unread' - WORKING
2. Show the count bubble on top op logged in user's display name - WORKING
3. On clicking the notification, hide the bubble and change post meta value with ajax only for the posts in the wp_query from 'unread' to 'read' so that the count is only visible next when there's a new post with meta value 'unread' - HOW?
4. Show a dropdown of all latest posts with meta value 'read' - maybe another query?

Here's my code for count bubble.

```
add_shortcode('notify', 'notify_member');
    function notify_member() {
        global $current_user;
        get_currentuserinfo();
        $userid = $current_user->ID;
            $args = array(
                'posts_per_page' => '-1',
                'post_type' => 'answer',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'author__not_in' => $userid, //exclude user posts
                'meta_query' => array(
                        'relation' => 'AND',
                    array(
                        'key' => 'question_owner_id'
                        'value' => $userid, //only show posts for the user
                        'compare' => '='
                    ),
                        array(
                            'key' => '_read_answer'
                            'value' => 'unread', //only show unread posts
                            'compare' => '='
                        ),
                    )
                );
                $questions = new WP_Query( $args );
                $html = '';
                $html .= '<a href="#" class="count">'.$questions->found_posts.'</a>'; //total count
                return $html;
    }
```

I have looked at ajax like and vote tutorials, they tackle one post at a time. I will need the below to work for all returned posts from the query and change at tha same time.

```
            if( $questions->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $questions->have_posts() ) { $questions->the_post();
                 update_post_meta( $post->ID, '_read_answer', 'read' ); 
                }
            }
```

I am out of ideas, any direction is welcome. Thanks. P.S. I am not a coder, so please do explain a little.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498959/how-to-use-ajax-in-a-wordpress-shortcode/13614297#13614297) helps

Comment: Thank you so much. I will adapt it according to my requirements and get back to you

Comment: I have a working structure now. Thank you.

Comment: This answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498959/how-to-use-ajax-in-a-wordpress-shortcode/13614297#13614297 has helped me too. Thanks @brasofilo