# Wordpress, how to use AJAX to return result of shortcodes and change displayed forms on page

Tags: ajax, wordpress

Currently I am working on a wordpress site. What I want to do is:

Changing the used contact form (over shortcodes, done by a plugin), everytime the user changes his selection of options provided by a dropdownlist with one form as the default one.

I want to achieve this by using ajax. I could send the Index of the selected option to a php file, but I dont know how exactly I would execute the shortcode in php and return the result to the wp site.

Any information and advice would be great!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Use AJAX in a WordPress Shortcode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498959/how-to-use-ajax-in-a-wordpress-shortcode)

Comment: @brasofilo I´ve read the post, before I asked my question. I did not quite understand all of it. The main part I didnt get was how to run a shortcode in php and return just the html. Any advice on that one or could you tell me which part of your code in the other thread does that? Thanks!

Comment: You should say that in question then *"I've read the following post... etc etc"*. Sorry, I don't understand what's your problem, can you illustrate it with `code`?

Comment: @brasofilo I´ll remember! As you can see from my reputation I am very new to stackoverflow. Thats exactly my problem, I dont know how I should write the code... I want to pass the index of a dropdown list to a php script using ajax (I could do that), then in php, depending on the index I want to run a shortcode tag from a WP Plugin and return the resulting html and display it on the page. So dynamically change, in this case, the contact form depending on a premade choice. Hope that illustrates a bit better.