# Undefined wpdb after ajax call in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, database, wordpress

I am trying to access a database without reloading the page by using ajax. First the string is retreived from the input field.

```
<div class="row input search">
     <label>Findr</label>
     <input type="text" id="ppl" placeholder="Search.." autocomplete="off">
<div id="results"></div>
</div>
```

And here is the ajax:

```
function search() {
var query_value = $('#ppl').val();
if(query_value.length >= '4'){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../search.php?search="+query_value,
        data: { query: query_value},
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
            $("#results").html(html);
        }
    });
}return false;
}
```

And I have to use $wpdb in the search.php, but I get an error sying

> Call to a member function get_results() on a non-object in...

So I figured that $wpdb is undefined in search.php. I've read some examples on the official wordpress site but it's not that clear. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Can you show code from search.php?

Comment: WP and Ajax require [some specifics](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13614297/1287812)...

Comment: Not enough caffeine for me this morning. @brasofilo is right, WP has a specific way of dealing with ajax. I have deleted my answer from earlier.