# Ajax not working in front end of wordpress plugin shortcode

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Hi this my code for wordpress plugin

```
function my_action_callback() {
      check_ajax_referer( 'my-special-string', 'security' );

      $whatever = intval( $_POST['whatever'] );
      $whatever += 10;
      echo $whatever;
      die(); 
    }
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );
    add_shortcode('my_products','my_shortcode');

        function my_shortcode($atts)
        {
            extract(shortcode_atts(array(
                'id'=>''       
            ), $atts));
         ob_start();

         wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script', plugins_url( 'myplugin/js/example.js' ), array('jquery'), NULL, true);
         wp_localize_script( 'script-name', 'MyAjax', array(
             'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
             'security' => wp_create_nonce( 'my-special-string' )
          ));
        }
```

**example.js** code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  var data = {
    action: 'my_action',
    security : MyAjax.security,
    whatever: 1234
  };

  $.post(MyAjax.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
    alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
  });
});
```

It does not alert any values. why?
my shortcode **[my_products]**

Comment: open up the debug log in chrome and check the Network traffic, it will help you and us with more info

Comment: Or use the web developer tools in Firefox and do the same thing ^. Incidentally, you can use the `ajaxError()` function or just use `$.ajax({});` instead and in there you can define your on-error method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Use AJAX in a WordPress Shortcode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498959/how-to-use-ajax-in-a-wordpress-shortcode)

Comment: @brasofilo tell me to what i am doing wrong in above code

Comment: `enqueue` and `localize` are not using the same [handle](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script). The browser inspector would have told you that `MyAjax not defined`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to localize the script first before enqueuing it, also you are currently localizing `script-name` whilst enqueueing `my-script`.

Try this:

```
function my_shortcode($atts)
        {
            extract(shortcode_atts(array(
                'id'=>''       
            ), $atts));
         ob_start();
         // Register the script first.
         wp_register_script( 'script-name', plugins_url( 'myplugin/js/example.js' ), array('jquery'), NULL, true);
         // Now localize it.
         wp_localize_script( 'script-name', 'MyAjax', array(
             'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
             'security' => wp_create_nonce( 'my-special-string' )
          ));
          // Now enqueue the script
          wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name')
        }
```

Comment: i fixed that. but it alert 0 always. why?

Comment: I suggest you log the response to the console of either firebug or chrome developer tools with `console.log(response)` and see what it contains, also have a look at the network traffic and see what is being returned.

Comment: most likely this is the result of intval...change your php function to test, just echo something else instead of $whatever, my guess is 0 will be gone.