# Using custom php functions in jquery - wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, plugins

I have a main plugin file that requires getuser.php (also plugin file).
In getuser.php I have written a function getuser()

Now in the main plugin file I'm trying to call this function with the following code:

main plugin file:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: FixFormData
Description: If you want to autocomplete a form with existing data, this plugin is for you.
Version: 1.1
Author: Stijn Aerts
Author URI: http://stijnaerts.be
License: GPL2
*/

require( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'menu.php');
//require_once( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'getuser.php');

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'ajax_lookup_userdata' );

function ajax_lookup_userdata(){

    if (!is_admin()) {
            wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
        }
    ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    jQuery('#input_1_2').change(function(){showUserName(this.value);});
        function showUserName(str){
            if(str==''){jQuery('#input_1_3').val('');}
        jQuery.get("<?php echo plugins_url() . '/FixFormData/getuser.php'; ?>", { q: str }, function(response){
                    var parsed = JSON.parse(response);
                    var arr = [];
                    for(var x in parsed){ arr.push(parsed[x]);}
                    jQuery('#input_1_3').val(arr[1]);
                    jQuery('#input_1_4').val(arr[2]);
            });
        }
    });
</script>
<?php
}
?>
```

getuser.php:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['q']) && !empty($_POST['q'])) {
        getuser($_POST['q']);
        exit;
    }

 function getuser($str)
{
    //$q = intval($_GET['q']);
    //include "../../../wp-load.php";
    global $wpdb;

    $myoption =  get_option( 'fixformdata_options' );
    $myoptionValue = maybe_unserialize( $myoption );    

    $result2 = $wpdb->get_row
    (
        $wpdb->prepare
        (
            "SELECT * FROM {$myoptionValue[tablename]} WHERE personeelsNummer = %d", $str
        )
    );

    if($result2) 
    {
        echo  json_encode( $result2 );
    }
}
?>
```

This still doesn't work.

Comment: You are trying to call a php function with javascript?  You can't do that

Comment: Yes I know, i also tried <?php echo getuser() ?> among other things

Comment: What does `getuser()` do? Does it return a variable?

Comment: It returns json data

Comment: Well you might want to try out `wp_localize_script`. This way you can pass the json information to jQuery. A great reference for this is: [https://pippinsplugins.com/use-wp_localize_script-it-is-awesome/](https://pippinsplugins.com/use-wp_localize_script-it-is-awesome/). The comments are useful as well.

Comment: Observations: 1) `wp_footer` only runs on frontend, so you don't need `is_admin()`. 2) Instead of `wp_footer`, use `wp_enqueue_scripts`. 3) Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498959/how-to-use-ajax-in-a-wordpress-shortcode/) for an AJAX example (Federico's tip for Pippin's article is quite good too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think wp_localize_script is what you're looking for. 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script

You can keep javascript and php separated by passing json data to javascript files and wordpress will do that in a clean and elegant way.

But if what you have to do needs to be done with a ajax request and not on page load than you have to use the wp_ajax_ hook a good tutorial here:
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/18/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress/

Comment: Hi I have made a new question, as I edited my code totally.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25566254/getting-data-from-database-and-use-it-to-complete-a-form-wordpress

Answer (score 2):

You need to send the data to the url where your function is located

```
$(function() {

function showUserName(str) {
    if (str === '') {
        $('#input_1_3').val('');
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'getuser.php', //where your function is located
        data: { whatever: value }, //post data $_POST['whatever'] = value
        success: function(data) {
            var data = JSON.parse(data); //whatever the server echoes will end up in data
            $('#input_1_3').val(data[0]);
            $('#input_1_4').val(data[1]);
        }
    });
}

$('#input_1_2').change(function() {
    showUserName($(this).val());
});
});
```

You should also make sure your php code is ready to respond to that request.

```
    <?php 

    if (isset($_POST['whatever']) && !empty($_POST['whatever'])) {
        getuser($_POST['whatever']);
        exit;
    }

    function getuser($str) {
        // logic and stuff

        echo json_encode(["whatever", "you want to return"]);
    } 

    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I edited my code and all of my code is now in the OP, it still doesn't work though...

Comment: also, please keep in mind that this is for wordpress and I need correct hooking, I had a good solution that was working but it didn't had corredt hooking.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add a type to the ajax request. To be completely honest, I don't know anything about wordpress, but this should work. What exactly are you returning? Can I see the php?

Comment: Is "getuser.php" in a subdirectory? That needs to be specified in the url. Also, have you tried alerting the data that is returned from the server to see what it contains?

Comment: I'm just returning some database data, text. What php do u want to see?

Comment: Whatever is relevant. What do you get when you alert(data)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60196/discussion-between-dandan-and-stijn26).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your `getuser()` function is coded in PHP, correct?  Assuming so, you won't be able to call it via jQuery.  PHP is a server-side language.  Once it has ran, that's it, it can't be accessed again without reloading the page, and still only by server-side languages.  jQuery is client-side scripting, something done on the users computer.

Basically, you'd need the `getuser()` function to be in some form of JavaScript, or to output what you want it to display and have the jQuery display the page.