# Use WP_Query() from plugin with AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, access-control

I’m working on a WordPress plugin and I need to make a query to the DB using AJAX.

My function looks like this:

```
function kokoku() {
    if ($(".kokoku_head").height() === 0) {
       $.ajax({
           url: 'location_query.php', 
           success: function(data) {
               $(".kokoku_head_bup").html(data);
           }
        });
     }
};
```

Now in my location_query.php if I go for something static, like:

```
Echo “hey!”;
Return
```

Everything goes well. However the minute I add `WP_Query()` I get a No `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` Error.

I have tried adding

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

to the location_query.php file but the problem still persists.

My best guess is `WP_Query()` is calling yet another file which is is returning the `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` error and were I should add the `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` too, but I don’t know which file that might be.

Comment: AJAX in WordPress doesn't work that way. https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: Yes, totally wrong approach... This answer of mine has a fully working example, should be easy to adapt to your needs: [How to Use AJAX in a WordPress Shortcode?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13498959/1287812)