# pass function to .load PHP (WordPress)

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

So I have a single.php which contains this.

```php
$('#ajax').load('<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/test.php?choices=<?php echo $post_id; ?>');
```

This loads test.php into this

```html
<div id="ajax"></div>
```

The test.php loads in perfectly. But I want to use a function from functions.php
In single.php I can perform any function from functions.php. Since this is the WordPress standard.

But when I try to use a function from it in test.php I get an error.
This is the error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_theme_support() in /customers/9/9/c/papercraftplaza.com/httpd.www/wp-content/themes/papercraftplazaV2/functions.php on line 2

This is everything that is in test.php. The functions I want to use are currently a comment. How would I include it so I can use my function?

```php
<?php
include "functions.php";

$_GET['choices'];
$passedvar = reset($_GET);

//setPostDownloads($passedvar);
//echo getPostDownloads($passedvar);

?>
<p>You downloaded papercraft: <?php echo reset($_GET); ?></p>
```

Comment: Does `functions.php` load the wordpress files?

Comment: No, functions.php just contains all my functions nice and tidy in one php file. In wordpress i can just use the function setPostDownloads($passedvar); on my index.php or any page.

But for some reason it won't work in my .load test.php

Comment: Maybe this is helpful: https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress-a-real-world-example/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to include wp-load.php apparently
This should replace the include functions.
It works now!

```
  $path = preg_replace('/wp-content.*$/','',__DIR__);
  $path = preg_replace('/wp-content(?!.*wp-content).*/','',__DIR__);
  include($path.'wp-load.php');
```

Comment: I works but is very very crazy :) Great problem solving skills though! When you include `wp-load.php`, you're calling *the whole WP all over again* in a single/simple Ajax call.... [This is how to use Ajax in WP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13614297/1287812)